# "firebase is not defined" what is the problem?

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack, firebase-realtime-database

I am using WebPack and firebase. The main webpack file (app.js) looks like this:

```
import "./sass/style.scss";
import "./js/firebase.js";
import firebase from 'firebase';
import database from "firebase/database";
import auth from "firebase/auth";
import "./js/firebase.js";
import "./js/utils.js";
import "./js/auth.js";
import "./js/forms.js";
import "./js/listRequests.js";
import "./js/picturefill.js";
```

So, my "firebase.js" looks like this:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "something",
    authDomain: "something",
    databaseURL: "something",
    projectId: "something",
    storageBucket: "something",
    messagingSenderId: "something",
    appId: "something"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let ref = database.ref("something");
```

I am specifically censored all values to something, dont worry about that.
And the thing i get on every page where i attach my "bundle.js" (main file of webpack) is

```
firebase is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:667)
    at n (bundle.js:1)
    at Module.<anonymous> (bundle.js:2760)
    at n (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
    at bundle.js:1
```

So I just want to know, what is the problem here? Could you please help me? I am new in webpack and firebase. Thanks!

Comment: On the first code block you are importing `"./js/firebase.js"` two times. Check that please. Also, are you using VueCLI?.

Comment: yep, but anyway it doesnt work.
what about VueCLI, no, i am not using that.
i am using only webpack and vanilla javascript.
thanks for your answer, i am still trying to find answer for that question.